# .append changes added elements in Swift array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append

I'm currently working on a messaging app for iOS to excel my Swift skills but I've run into a weird problem. I keep all the messages between two people in an array called '`messages`'. The data will be fetched from a FireBase database, but for now (I'm still working on actually laying out the pages), they're just kept in an on-device array. I've declared a class called `TextMessage` by the way. It just keeps the values `text: String` and `isSender: Bool`. Anyways, I declare my array as follows:

```
var messages: [TextMessage] = []
```

And I have a button which calls `didPressSendButton` when clicked: `sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressSendButton), for: .touchUpInside)`

That function is defined as follows:

```
@objc func didPressSendButton() {
    
    guard let messageText = textField.text else {
        return
    }
    
    if messageText == "" {
        return
    }
    
    let newMessage: TextMessage = TextMessage.zero
    newMessage.text = messageText
    newMessage.isSender = true
    messages.append(newMessage)
    
    messageTable.reloadData()
    scrollToBottom()
    updateUI()
    
    textField.text = ""
    
}
```

For some reason though, the `append` method changes *all* elements in the array. So if I first send a message with the text 'Hi' and then send another one, 'Hey', the first one gets changed. I've printed the array's values and sure enough, it holds two messages with the text 'Hey' instead 1 'Hi' and 1 'Hey'. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: What is `TextMessage.zero`? I suspect it's a stored property which is returning the same one `TextMessage` instance every time, which you're modifying over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append should work properly. What it looks like to me is that TextMessage.zero is a static property of type TextMessage. Every time you call that, you just reference the same object, change the text, and append a reference to it in your array. So your array just has a growing number of references to the same object.

Having a static variable like that would work in a struct, but not a class because it is a reference type. Instead, make zero a static func that creates a new object.

Comment: or just make sure the property is a computed property rather than a stored property.

Comment: Fantastic! I made 'zero' as an extension to the class TextMessage to have it completely initialised but as a placeholder for a value that would come later. It worked perfectly now that I changed it to a static function. Thank you so much!